# (Beginners Python) Creating if/else statements dependent on user input?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to create a simple script that will will ask a question to which the user will input an answer (Or a prompt with selectable answers could appear?), and the program would output a response based on the input.

For example, if I were to say

```
prompt1=input('Can I make this stupid thing work?')
```

I would have something along the lines of

```
if prompt1='yes': 
    print('Hooray, I can!')

else prompt1='No':
    print('Well I did anyway!')

elif prompt1=#an answer that wouldn't be yes or no
    #repeat prompt1
```

I'm probably going about this the wrong way. Please be as descriptive as possible as this is a learning exercise for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `==` to compare equality, and use the `else` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close.  Read a good tutorial :)

```
#!python3
while True:
    prompt1=input('Can I make this stupid thing work?').lower()

    if prompt1 == 'yes':
       print('Hooray, I can!')
    elif prompt1 == 'no':
       print('Well I did anyway!')
    else:
       print('Huh?') #an answer that wouldn't be yes or no
```

- `while True` will loop the program forever.
- Use `==` to test for equality.
- Use `.lower()` to make it easier to test for answers regardless of case.
- `if/elif/elif/.../else` is the correct sequence for testing.

Here's a Python 2 version:

```
#!python2
while True:
    prompt1=raw_input('Can I make this stupid thing work?').lower()

    if prompt1 == 'yes':
       print 'Hooray, I can!'
    elif prompt1 == 'no':
       print 'Well I did anyway!'
    else:
       print 'Huh?' #an answer that wouldn't be yes or no
```

- `raw_input` is used instead of `input`.  `input` in Python 2 will tries to interpret the input as Python code.
- `print` is a statement instead of a function.  Don't use `()` with it.

Comment: I copy/pasted this into my PyCharm, and I get this error when I try to input an answer. (yes or no)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shawn/PycharmProjects/helloworld/Test Prograsm.py", line 3, in <module>
    prompt1=input('Can I make this stupid thing work?').lower()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined

Comment: You must be using Python 2.x instead.  `print()` is a function in Python 3 so I assumed you are using Python 3.  use `raw_input` in Python 2.  Update your question tags to indicate your Python version.

Comment: Oh you're right! Completely my fault. Thank you for the learning experience. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another example, this time as a function.

```
def prompt1():
    answer = raw_input("Can I make this stupid thing work?").lower()
    if answer == 'yes' or answer == 'y':
        print "Hooray, I can!"
    elif answer == 'no' or answer == 'n':
        print "Well I did anyway!"
    else:
        print "You didn't pick yes or no, try again."
        prompt1()

prompt1()
```